# Eloquent Laravel consulta MySQL

Tags: laravel

Hola amigos es que me gustaria hacer esta consulta en laravel

```
LEFT JOIN subgrupo ON usuario_grupo.grupo_id = subgrupo.grupo_id OR subgrupo.id = usuario_grupo.subgrupo_id
```

Ya se que falta el select pero solo necesito saber como escribir el OR en eloquent

Entiendo que seria el left asi

```
->leftjoin('subgrupo', 'usuario_grupo.grupo_id', '=', 'subgrupo.grupo_id OR subgrupo.id = usuario_grupo.subgrupo_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar como [segundo argumento](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#advanced-join-clauses) en el método `join` una *closure* y entonces si establecer la primera condición con el método `on` y la segunda con el método `orOn` del siguiente modo:

```
->leftjoin('subgrupo', function($query) {
    $query->on('usuario_grupo.grupo_id', '=', 'subgrupo.grupo_id')
        ->orOn('subgrupo.id', '=', 'usuario_grupo.subgrupo_id');
}).....................
```